# Built in audio player?

Tags: plugins, theme-development, audio

I was certain that WordPress had built in a basic audio player. Am I mistaken. I cant find any evidence of one anywhere, just plugins ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WordPress does **not** have a built-in audio player. You will need to use one of [the myriad audio-player Plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=audio%20player) available.

Answer (score 2):

You can find a variety of media players online at [wordpress.org/extend/plugins](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins). If you're going for something with support for a bunch of file types, I'd go with MediaElement.